# ODE - question to the solution of $y''+4y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

The solution of the ODE (using the constant coefficients method) is of the form  $$y(x)=e^{\alpha x}(c_1 cos(\beta x)+c_2 sin(\beta x)) \quad \quad (1)$$

which in this case is $$y(x)=c_1 cos(2x)+c_2 sin(2x)  \quad \quad (2)$$  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27(t)%2B4y(t)%3D0

the solution of the the quadratic equation resulting from the ODE $r^2+4=0$ is a complex number
$r=\frac{\sqrt{-8}}{2}= \sqrt{-2} = \sqrt{2} i$

so $\alpha=0$ 
complex number has a form $\alpha + \beta i$ **why then $\beta=2$ and not $\beta=\sqrt{2}$ in (2)?**

Comment: $r^2+4=0 \not \implies r=\frac{\sqrt{-8}}{2}= \sqrt{-2} = \sqrt{2} i$

Comment: I don't get what you want to say

Comment: See my answer, and I also suggest another look at the quadratic formula.

Comment: I see,  $r=\frac{\sqrt{-16}}{2}= 2 i$, dyscalculia...

Comment: The equation is easier to solve in this case by just subtracting 4 and taking the square root. I think one is less likely to make a mistake using that method as opposed to using the quadratic formula which seems to be the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Careful: with the quadratic formula, $a=1, b=0, c=4$. The discriminant is $-16,$ not $-8$ ($b^2-4ac$).

Anytime we have complex roots $u+iv$ from the characteristic equation, we end up having $e^{ux} \left(\cos vx + \sin vx \right)$ as a solution.